# how to use sed to pull out data from a hex file

Tags: sed

I want to use sed to pull out data from a hex file but i dont want any hex formats output to the screen

I'm wanting to pull out any words from A to Z or a to z that have a minimum length of 5 characters and a maximum length of 25 characters

Is there a way to do this with sed and awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use grep:

```
grep -aoE '([A-Za-z]){5,25}' file
```

- `-o` only prints the matching strings (not available in all versions of grep)
- `-a` treats the input as ascii even if it's not (otherwise grep won't print the matches)
- `-E` uses extended regular expressions so the syntax is a bit nicer

Comment: If i wanted to also select if any numbers were between a - z would i just use '([A-Za-z0-9]){5,25}'

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\n/!s/\S\+/\n&\n/g;/^[[:alpha:]]\{5,25\}\n/P;D' file
```

This splits each line into non-space words and then prints only those words that consist of between 5 and 25 alphabetic characters.